# NextJS Error: Cannot find module 'caniuse-lite/data/features/css-unicode-bidi'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js

Error trying to build.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'caniuse-lite/data/features/css-unicode-bidi'
```

Already tried to add "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001281" and "^1.0.30001390", but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried: `"caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001281"` and `"caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001390"` but not worked.

Finally I added `"caniuse-lite": "1.0.30001393"` (without the ˆ prefix) manually to package.json then run `npm update` and worked.

Reference: https://pullanswer.com/questions/app-fails-to-load-after-running-npm-run-dev-from-fresh-project